# How do I get an image to enlarge on a click, center in the webpage and then return to its original position on another click using JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Here is the code I have going for me right now. As you can see the JS works great but wont return the image on a second click. The CSS, I cant seem to get it to move the image to the center.

```js
function enlargeImg(img) {
    img.style.transform = "scale(1.5)";
    img.style.transition =
        "transform 0.25s ease";
}
```

```css
img {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="heading">
            <h3>Photo <span>Gallery</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box">

            <div class="dream">

                <img src="./tucson/DSC03046.JPG" onclick="enlargeImg(this)">
                <img src="./tucsonBW/nutsNBoltsBW.jpg">
                <img src="./nature/deadTree.JPEG">
                <img src="./nature/honeyBee.JPG">
                <img src="./tucsonBW/mailBoxBW.jpg">

            </div>
```

Comment: check this out : https://codepen.io/Avi-Qiyan/pen/gOdJBYN

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the previously enlarged image returns to its original size when another image is clicked, you can keep track of the currently enlarged image and reset its size before enlarging the new image.

```js
var currentImgId;

function enlargeImg(imgId) {
  var img = document.getElementById(imgId);

  // reset size of previously enlarged image, if any
  if (currentImgId) {
    var currentImg = document.getElementById(currentImgId);
    currentImg.classList.remove("enlarged");
  }

  // enlarge clicked image
  img.classList.add("enlarged");

  // set current image id to clicked image id
  currentImgId = imgId;
}
```

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.enlarged {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <h3>Photo <span>Gallery</span></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="dream">
      <img id="img1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar1.png" onclick="enlargeImg(this.id)" />
      <img id="img2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar2.png" onclick="enlargeImg(this.id)" />
      <img id="img3" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_avatar3.png" onclick="enlargeImg(this.id)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is close to what I have in mind but not exactly what I am looking for. I would like the image I click on to enlarge and position itself in the middle of the screen, then when clicked again return to its original size and place.

Comment: you can write css for that, thats not a problem

Comment: I understand, I guess the image will take up a large area of screen so I want it to close after you click the image again. I will play with the code you marked up and see if I can get it running in that way. I am not great in JS at all but I do understand it some.

Comment: @johnnyC I updated the code check now, if you find this helpful don't forget accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: This is better but I need it to close the image when you click the image again. I think I will get it thought.